# LabelMaker style alá TEX

Tags: tables

I don't own a label maker machine but I've found some A4 paper which have a sticky side. Therefore they can be used as labels. I wrote the following code where the `\newLabel` command should make a label with a dotted box around it. The outline box is used as a guide when cutting the label with scissors.

One problem that I'm facing is that the boxes I create don't get resized to the words length. This wastes a lot of paper. They should be as close to each other and have an arbitary padding between the borders and letters. Do you have any tips? How may I achieve this goal?

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\geometry{margin=0cm} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewEnviron{elaboration}{
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle,minimum width=0.9\textwidth] (m) {
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \BODY
    \end{minipage}};

\draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\newLabel}[1] {
    \begin{elaboration}
        \uppercase{#1}
    \end{elaboration}
}


\begin{document}

\newLabel{$H_2O$}
\newLabel{salt}
\newLabel{High Voltage}
\newLabel{Danger}
\newLabel{DO not touch}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following PDF: 
[image]

What I want is something like this (with good padding between borders and letters):

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is better to use tables than this method. I'm new to TEX so all comments are appreciated.

Comment: Your problem (I think) is the `minimum width=0.9\textwidth` option you have given. Remove this, and each box should be the appropriate padding. Then, you can look at the `outer sep` option to control the spacing to the border. Actually, you can just provide the `draw` option to the `node` and remove the additional `draw` command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `varwidth` package to adjust the width. Also adjust `inner` and `outer sep` values as suitable. The option `minimum width=0.9\textwidth` is not necessary and the separate `\draw` command in redundant as you can draw in the options of node itself.

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\geometry{margin=0cm} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewEnviron{elaboration}{
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle,draw,dashed,outer sep=4pt,inner sep=10pt,execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}},
   execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}] (m) {\BODY};

%\draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\newLabel}[1] {%
    \begin{elaboration}%
        \uppercase{#1}
    \end{elaboration}
}


\begin{document}

\newLabel{$H₂O$}
\newLabel{salt}
\newLabel{High Voltage}
\newLabel{Danger}
\newLabel{DO not touch}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove `\par` from the definition of `elaboration` like

```
\NewEnviron{elaboration}{
%\par     %%<--------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle,draw,dashed,outer sep=4pt,inner sep=10pt,execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}},
   execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}] (m) {\BODY};

%\draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

You get

[image]

Comment: Ah this is awesome! :) Thanks for your time.